# [Migration from Python to R]: plot dataframe columns and selection of ALL data in a column

Tags: r

I am coming from Python and I am moving my first steps with R. I have a dataframe of floating point numbers (which I opened from a file with read.csv) with two columns, say

```
vec['a']
vec['b']
```

and I would like to plot vac['b'] versus vec['a'], I tried

```
plot(vec['a'], vec['b'])
```

but it's not working. I tried something like

```
plot(vec[1, 1:100], vec[2, 1:100])
```

and it works! But I can't write

```
plot(vec[1, :], vec[2, :])
```

in order to select ALL data in each column as I would do in Python or Matlab. Could you suggest me how to plot dataframe column vec[2] versus dataframe column vec[1] and/or how to select all data in a column, please?

Comment: Have you tried looking for `subsetting in R`? Something like this contains the answer to your question: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/subsetting.htm

Comment: Also recommended would be the [Lists and Data Frames section of An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists-and-data-frames).

Comment: Also, are you sure your data frame has two columns? The code you show would suggest it has two rows. Matrices and data.frames in R are indexed `[row, column]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you use single square brackets for indexing in a data.frame (i.e. `df[]`), you get data frame as output.

And the plot function is not meant for plotting data.frames.

Solution: If you want to plot the graph with two columns as axes of the graph, you should do this:

```
plot(vec[['a']], vec[['b']])
```

When we do indexing using double square brackets (i.e. `df[[]]`), a vector of the specific type (say, numeric, integer, character, factor etc.) is returned. So, the plotting is successful.